# Which crew skills do instant 60s get?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Is there a list somewhere of which classes get which crew skills when you create an instant 60?

I have all the ACs on Imp side at reasonable levels (55+) but I don't always bother with the crew skills on all my characters because it's time- and money-consuming.
So to fill up my missing crew skills a bit for end game, I want to use my free 60, but I need to know which crew skills go to which AC.

So far "we" know that Mercenary gets:

- Armormech
- Scavenging
- Underworld Trading

Does anyone know what the other ACs get, both Imp and Rep?
I'm expecting this to be a question that will need to be answered by multiple people.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a lot simpler than you're expecting.  Tech classes (Smuggler, Trooper, Agent, and Bounty Hunter) get what you described, and Force classes (Consular, Knight, Inquisitor, and Warrior)  get Synthweaving, Archaeology, and Underworld Trading.  Here's one [source on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/swtor/comments/3pwuxe/question_about_new_level_60_crew_skills/cwa3ra0) and [another on the official forums](http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?t=845770).

Comment: The source on the official forum is actually my thread :) but i wasn't getting a lot of replies on it at first.